# ArangoDB Spring Data 2, java.lang.Object / invalid map type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, arangodb

I have recently upgraded to Spring Boot 2 (and therefore Spring data 2) and have the latest Arango java driver and arango-spring-data versions (5.0.1 and 3.1.1 respectively)

I'm now having problems fetching a property with type `java.lang.Object`

I get this error

```
.... due to HttpClientErrorException: {"status":"BAD_REQUEST","timestamp":"2018-11-10 17:20:07","message":"Bad request. The server cannot complete the request as it is invalid.","detailMessage":"Unsupported Map type: java.lang.Object","invalidParameters":[]}
```

I can see that in the `DefaultArangoConverter` if the type is Object it's been treated as if it were a map...

```
if (typeToUse.isMap() || ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT.equals(typeToUse)) {
    return readMap(typeToUse, source);
}
```

....

in `readMap(..)`

```
final Map<Object, Object> map = CollectionFactory.createMap(type.getType(), keyType, source.size());
```

CollectionFactory is used to make the "map" - and it's not happy.

```
CollectionFactory.java
} else if (!Map.class.isAssignableFrom(mapType)) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Map type: " + mapType.getName());
```

Does anyone else get this?
I may have config'd incorreclty, but I'm using fairly out-of-the-box config.

**Update:**
If the type is `Map` it works ok, but if the map contains a map (ie in one of the 'values') I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the current version of arangodb-spring-data.

I already created a [PR](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/pull/135) on github which fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for that, super fast response!